# Issue with transitioning to UI-router child state from parent state

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I've tried looking at other threads for help in this regard but to no avail. I understand I'm putting into use nested states and also tried absolute/relative routes but it does not transition to attributeDefinition state from searchResults. I'm using UI Router for state transition with the following files ...

```
<!-- index.html page -->
<div ai-body>
    <!-- AngularUI View Pane -->
    <div class="ai-content content" id="ai-content" ui-view></div>
</div>

//index.router.js: Routes
.state('searchResults', {         //Parent state
        url: "/searchResults/{app}?keyword",
        templateUrl: "app/searchResults/searchResults.html",
        ncyBreadcrumb: { label: 'Search Results' }
       })
       //Attribute Definition
        .state('searchResults.attributeDefinition', {    //child state
             url: "/attributeDefinition/{action}",
             templateUrl: "app/attributeDefinition/attributeDefinition.html",
             ncyBreadcrumb: { label: 'Create Attribute Definition' }
            })

<!-- searchResults state -->
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref=".attributeDefinition({action: 'create'})">
                    Create new definition
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve loading a nested state in the unnamed ui-view of the parent state with the following configuration of $stateProvider. It's making use of targeting unnamed view (as opposed to relative) using the 'views' attribute. Might look straight-forward but I did not find the online documentation easy to interpret nor were any online examples offering this solution. Refer documentation for more information, here [ http://bit.ly/VLKhGg ] -

`$stateProvider
            //Parent state
            .state('searchResults', {
                url: "searchResults/{app}?keyword",
                views: {"@" : { url: "/searchResults/{app}?keyword",
                                templateUrl: "app/searchResults/searchResults.html"  } }
            })
                //Child state
                .state('searchResults.attributeDefinition', {
                    url: "/attributeDefinition/{action}",
                    parent: 'searchResults',
                    views: {"@" : { url: '/attributeDefinition/{action}', 
                                    templateUrl: "app/attributeDefinition/attributeDefinition.html"  } }
                })`